# Python gets KeyError in put images FPDF

Tags: python, fpdf

Anyone who can help me about FPDF error because I was trying to regenerate PDF, but got the following FPDF error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1230, in output
   self.close()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 322, in close
   self._enddoc()   # close document
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1868, in _enddoc
   self._putresources()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1791, in _putresources
   self._putimages()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1706, in _putimages
   del info['data']
KeyError: 'data'
```

The template has images but I'm not sure about the issue. Please refer below.

```
    def start(self, data, display=''):
        """ Start PDF """

        content = data['data']
        file_name = data['file_name']

        self.front_page(data)
        self.render_data(content)
        self.output(file_name, "F")
```

The issue is in this part of the pdf library:

```
 def _putimages(self):
        filter=''
        if self.compress:
            filter='/Filter /FlateDecode '
        i = [(x[1]["i"],x[1]) for x in self.images.items()]
        i.sort()
        for idx,info in i:
            self._putimage(info)
            del info['data']
            if 'smask' in info:
                del info['smask']
```

Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj8ar.png

Comment: Hey there! Can you share your code? Even better; a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: `content` doesn't contain what you think it does. Are you able to share what printing `content` shows?

Comment: Hi @Bob, there's no problem with the content or data.  The issue is on the closing of the pdf because it keep asking about the data in _putimages function in the pdf library.

Comment: @LyjenLovendino are you using `pdf = fpdf.FPDF()`, if so can you share the code where you invoke this

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue,What helped me is to initialise pdf=FPDF() every time either inside a function or while calling recursively

Answer (score -1):

I used [FPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2) for image processing and solved it with the way of initialization.
Thanks